# Parsing a PostgreSQL result object in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am writing an app that needs to quickly process hundreds of thousands of rows of data, so I've looked into nesting raw SQL in my Ruby code using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`, which is working beautifully. However whenever I run it I get the following Object as a result:

```
#<PG::Result:0x007fe158ab18c8 status=PGRES_TUPLES_OK ntuples=0 nfields=1 cmd_tuples=0>
```

I've googled around and can't find a way to parse the PG Result into something actually useful. Is there any built-in PG way to do this, or a workaround, or anything really?

Here is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT row_to_json(row(company_name, ccn_short_title, title))
FROM contents
WHERE contents.company_name = '#{company_name}'
AND contents.title = '#{title}';
```

Comment: Don't use raw SQL unless you absolutely can't avoid it. Writing raw SQL often ties you directly to a specific DBM which means portability and maintenance problems and negates the advantages of using an ORM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually `PG::Result` responds to many well-known methods from `Enumerable` module. You can output them all to watch for the desired ones:

```
query = "SELECT row_to_json(row) from (select * from users) row"
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
result.methods - Object.methods
# => returns an array of methods which can be used
```

For example, you could iterate the results and map them to something more suitable...

```
result.map do |row|
  JSON.parse(row["row_to_json"])
end
# => returns familiar hashes
```

Get a desired result hash by its index...

```
result[0]
```

And much more.